# How to SOQL for Company Currencies?

Tags: soql

Can I SOQL for a company's Active Currencies (see image below)? I cannot find documentation around this.

[image]

Comment: What is the use case for you wanting to query it?

Comment: I am trying to see if test classes can see these Active Currencies. I suspect NOT but I want to be sure.

Comment: btw- TestClasses can see Active Currencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably query [`CurrencyType`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_datedconversionrate.htm) or [`DatedConversionRate`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_DatedConversionRate.htm), not sure if they are available via SOQL query in Apex. Unfortunately I do not have an org with multi-currency enabled to verify.

Comment: You are right. It worked. I was querying for the wrong object (SELECT Id, IsoCode FROM DatedConversionRate). CurrencyType works!